# Below code for PLP page Sort-By Price Low-High & High-Low working properly in M2.3.6 EE but not in M2.4.5 EE , any solution?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, magento2.4.5

**Lokesh/CatalogExtended/etc/di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Lokesh_CatalogExtended_Block_Toolbar" sortOrder="10" type="Lokesh\CatalogExtended\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Lokesh_CatalogExtended_Model_Config" sortOrder="11" type="Lokesh\CatalogExtended\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Lokesh/CatalogExtended/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Toolbar.php**

```
    namespace Lokesh\CatalogExtended\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar
{
    public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
    ) {
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);

    if ($currentOrder) {
        if ($currentOrder == 'high_to_low') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }
    }

    return $result;
    }}
```

**Lokesh/CatalogExtended/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php**

```
    namespace Lokesh\CatalogExtended\Plugin\Catalog\Model;
class Config
{
      public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
      $options
      ) {

          $options['low_to_high'] = __('Price - Low To High');
          $options['high_to_low'] = __('Price - High To Low');
          $options['position'] = __('Best Sellers');
          $options['name'] = __('Name');

          unset($options['price']);
          return $options;
      }}
```

Comment: **Later i found the Solution !**

`  $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        
            if ($currentOrder) {
                if ($currentOrder == 'high_to_low') {
                    $collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
                } elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high') {
                    $collection->setOrder('price', 'asc');
                }
            }
            count($collection);
            $result = $proceed($collection);
            return $result;`